# How to animate Navigationbar like AppStore App Detail Page?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, navigationbar

**Navigationbar like AppStore**

[image]

Transparent Navigation bar first and when app scroll up Navigation bar become visible.

Please check the effect in Gif File added with this question

Comment: making the navgation bar transparent and the using the scrollVIewDelegate to detect when scrool up change transparence in navigation bar

Comment: @kjoe canyou please give sample code for that?

Comment: @BrittoThomas kindly check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First setup the navigation bar transparent like below

```
// Makes the navigation bar transparent
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Now uses the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll` to detect the percentage of the the scroll view and based on that change the alpha

```
  // MARK: UIScrollViewDelegate

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        super.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)

        let maximumVerticalOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height
        let currentVerticalOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let percentageVerticalOffset = currentVerticalOffset / maximumVerticalOffset

        let color = UIColor.init(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: percentageVerticalOffset)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = color
    }
```

Hope it is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to make Navigation bar same like App Store I suggest you to remove the default navigation bar & create a custom Topbar by taking UIView & set up its frame as a Topbar.

The main reason is the default navigation bar is not look wise & behaviour wise looks good on iPhone X & such phones.

Another most important thing is may be you will be able to achieve it by default Navigation bar but Apple always keeps modifying the navigation system & due to that you can see deprecated methods specially in navigation.

So I better suggest if you create custom navigation it will be easily controllable & there will be no chances of the deprecated methods & all.

Hope this helps to you.